# VBA always crash on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have some code that I make using Excel 2013. It works perfectly and when I try to run it on Excel 2010, the excel always does not respond, restarting the program and closing. I try to reopen it and the file sometimes goes with read-only or recovery mode so I can't even run my macro even I enable it.

Is there any way to fix this without updating the excel? any ideas?

NB: the laptop with Excel 2010 is not mine, it's my user laptop so if possible, I prefer to not change anything inside the laptop

here's the code

```
Public Const paramFolderPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Data"
Sub Sheet1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    OpenWorkbooks paramFolderPath 'Path collected from the folder parameter
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub OpenWorkbooks(sourceFolder As Variant)
    
    Dim sourceFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
    Dim masterWb, Sourcewb As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook
    Dim ext As String
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set masterWb = ThisWorkbook
    sourceFile = Dir(sourceFolder & "\") 'DIR gets the first file of the folder
    Do While sourceFile <> ""
        ext = Right(sourceFile, Len(sourceFile) - InStrRev(sourceFile, "."))
        If sourceFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name And (ext = "xlsm" Or ext = "xlsx") Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=sourceFolder & "\" & sourceFile, ReadOnly:=True
        Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
        'Copy only the first sheet of a workbook
        Sourcewb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=masterWb.Sheets(masterWb.Worksheets.Count)
        'Close the source workbook
        Sourcewb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set Sourcewb = Nothing
    End If
    sourceFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
Loop

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue with running code (from 2013) on a 2010 Excel is that there's bound to be issues of non-back-compatibility.   Without showing what code you're using, it's difficult to gauge if this is your case.

Comment: If you don't qualify objects or something similar, it's possible that by sheer chance the code works in 2013. Please do share your code.

Comment: @ewong edit my question with my code on it

Comment: @VBasic2008 done with editing my question

Comment: Comment out the `on error resume next` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Files in a Folder

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Const paramFolderPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Data"

Sub GetFirstWorkSheets()
    ImportFirstWorksheets paramFolderPath
End Sub

Sub ImportFirstWorksheets(ByVal sFolderPath As String)
    Const ProcName As String = "ImportFirstWorksheets"
    
    Dim fCount As Long
    Dim wbCount As Long
    Dim wsCount As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const ExtensionsList As String = "xlsm,xlsx"
    
    ' Check if files in folder.
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found in '" & sFolderPath & "'.", _
            vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Extensions() As String: Extensions = Split(ExtensionsList, ",")
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dwbPath As String: dwbPath = dwb.FullName
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim Ext As String
    Dim sFilePath As String
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        fCount = fCount + 1
        Ext = Right(sFileName, Len(sFileName) - InStrRev(sFileName, "."))
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Ext, Extensions, 0)) Then
            wbCount = wbCount + 1
            sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
            If StrComp(sFilePath, dwbPath, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                On Error GoTo WbError
                    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, , True)
                On Error GoTo ClearError
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            If Not swb Is Nothing Then
                If swb.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then ' only first worksheet
                    wsCount = wsCount + 1
                    swb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
                End If
                swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Set swb = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        sFileName = Dir ' next file in folder
    Loop

SafeExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
         
        MsgBox "Files Found: " & fCount & vbLf _
            & "Workbooks Found: " & wbCount & vbLf _
            & "Worksheets Copied: " & wsCount, vbInformation, ProcName
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
WbError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```